# anaconda activation bug on windows wsl2

Tags: python, anaconda, windows-subsystem-for-linux, activation

I'm trying to activate anaconda on wsl2.

anaconda version - Anaconda3-2021.05-Linux-x86_64
wsl distro - ubuntu 20.04.1

I'm getting this error on opening a new shell

`bash: eval: line 203: syntax error near unexpected token` ('`

Subsequent activation of other environments with `conda activate <envname>` fails with a similar error.

Help will be appreciated,
Roy

Comment: What exactly are you doing to activate it? If I'm not mistaken, if one installs Anaconda, the base environment is activated by default.

Comment: It is activated, but with the above error, and after that subsequent activation of other environments fail. It seems like wsl not parsing the eval command properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wsl adds environment variables from windows itself.
One of the paths in the path environment variable was missing an apostrophes.
That was the cause.